# PostGIS: Query z and m dimensions (linestringzm)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

### Question

I have a system with multiple `linestringzm`, where the data is structured the following way: `[x, y, speed:int, time:int]`. The data is structured this way to be able to use `ST_SimplifyVW` on the `x`, `y` and `z` dimensions, but I still want to be able to query the linestring based on the `m` dimension e.g. get all linestrings between a time interval.

Is this possible with PostGIS or am I structuring the data incorrectly for my use case?

### Example

- `z` = speed e.g. km/h
- `m` = Unix epoch time

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (id int NOT NULL, geom geometry(LineStringZM,4326), CONSTRAINT t_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'SRID=4326;LINESTRING ZM(30 10 5 1620980688, 30 15 10 1618388688, 30 20 15 1615710288, 30 25 20 1620980688)'::geometry);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2, 'SRID=4326;LINESTRING ZM(50 10 5 1620980688, 50 15 10 1618388688, 50 20 15 1615710288, 50 25 20 1620980688)'::geometry);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3, 'SRID=4326;LINESTRING ZM(20 10 5 1620980688, 20 15 10 1618388688, 20 20 15 1615710288, 20 25 20 1620980688)'::geometry);
```

- **Use case A: Simplify the geometry based on `x`, `y` and `z`**

  This can be accomplished by e.g. `ST_SimplifyVW` which keep the `m` dimension after simplification.
- **Use case B: Query geometry based on the `m` dimension**

  I have a set of `linestringzm` which I want to query based on my time dimension (`m`). The result is either the full geometry if all `m` is between e.g.`1618388000` and `1618388700` or the part of the geometry which satisfies the predicate. What is the most efficient way to query the data?

Comment: Can you show the `CREATE TABLE` statement and an `INSERT` so that we know what you mean?

Comment: You mean you want to write a query that checks if each point of your linestring has a dimension `m` that matchs a given range?

Comment: @SOK: is this what you're looking for `WITH j AS (
  SELECT id,geom, (ST_M((ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom)) AS mdim 
  FROM t 
) 
SELECT DISTINCT id,geom 
FROM j
WHERE mdim BETWEEN 1430 AND 1530` ?

Comment: @JimJones: I added an example which hopefully makes it more clear what I am trying to achieve :)

Comment: I also assume the linestrings have no id, is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check every single point of your LineString you could `ST_DumpPoints` them and get the `M` dimension with `ST_M`. After that extract the subset as a LineString containing the overlapping `M` values and apply `ST_MakeLine` with a `GROUP BY`:

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT id,geom,(ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom AS p 
  FROM t 
) 
SELECT id,ST_AsText(ST_MakeLine(p))
FROM j
WHERE ST_M(p) BETWEEN 1618388000 AND 1618388700
GROUP BY id;
```

Demo: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c975e7e2def8d3b41e79a2e2ac9f0468)

**Note**: Depending on your table and LineString sizes this query may become pretty slow, as values are being parsed in query time and therefore aren't indexed. Imho a more elegant alternative would be ..

.. 1) to create a `tstzrange` column

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN line_interval tstzrange;
```

.. 2) to properly index it

```
CREATE INDEX idx_t_line_interval ON t USING gist (line_interval);
```

.. and 3) to populate it with the time of `geom`'s *first* and *last* points:

```
UPDATE t SET line_interval = 
  tstzrange(
    to_timestamp(ST_M(ST_PointN(geom,1))),
    to_timestamp(ST_M(ST_PointN(geom,ST_NPoints(geom)))));
```

After that you can speed things up by checking wether the indexed column overlaps with a given interval. This will significantly improve query time:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE line_interval && tstzrange(
                        to_timestamp(1618138148), 
                        to_timestamp(1618388700));
```

Demo: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1b831de2087f3fcce9ef0c5984bc5e43)

Further reading:

- [ST_M](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.1/ST_M.html)
- [ST_PointN](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_PointN.html)
- [ST_NPoints](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_NPoints.html)
- [PostgreSQL Built-in Range Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN)

Comment: I updated the example with a primary key. Is it efficient to use `ST_DumpPoints` or would it make more sense to structure the data in another way for the sake of performance?