# How to query space-time points with index in PostGIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I got millions of points stored with a PointZM (lon,lat,depth, time epoch) geometry column

`ST_SetSRID(st_makepoint(longitude,latitude,-z,date_part('epoch', "timestamp"::timestamp)),4326) as timegeom`

I have created a `GIST(geometry gist_geometry_ops_nd)` index on the column

Now, how to query this in space and time?

I have tried using the &&& operator:

```
select * from huge_spatial_table 
where timegeom &&& st_3dmakebox(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(0.05278027,29.47846469,0,date_part('epoch', '2013-01-01'::timestamp)),4326), 
                                st_setsrid(st_makepoint(37.50180758,45.37019107,-50,date_part('epoch', '2018-01-01'::timestamp)),4326))
```

But the time dimension is not filtered when doing this.

When filtering time using st_m(geometry) it works, but the index is not used on the time dimension which is what I want.

```
select * from huge_spatial_table 
where timegeom &&& st_3dmakebox(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(0.05278027,29.47846469,0,date_part('epoch', '2013-01-01'::timestamp)),4326), 
                                st_setsrid(st_makepoint(37.50180758,45.37019107,-50,date_part('epoch', '2018-01-01'::timestamp)),4326)) 
and st_m(timegeom)>date_part('epoch', '2013-01-01'::timestamp)
and st_m(timegeom)<date_part('epoch', '2018-01-01'::timestamp)
```

Explain:

```
"Index Scan using idx_huge_spatial_table  on huge_spatial_table   (cost=0.55..2.78 rows=1 width=184)"
"  Index Cond: (timegeom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geometry)"
"  Filter: ((st_m(timegeom) > '1356998400'::double precision) AND (st_m(timegeom) < '1514764800'::double precision))"
```

Is it even possible to do spatio-temporal queries using an index in PostGIS?

Btw, I am using postgres 9.6 and PostGIS 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

You could create an extra index containing only the `M` dimension of your geometries, e.g. this will improve query time:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_t_geom_m ON huge_spatial_table (ST_M(geom));
```

###### Query plan without the index (100k random points):

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on huge_spatial_table  (cost=4.36..291.45 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=0 loops=1)
  Filter: ((st_m(timegeom) > '1356998400'::double precision) AND (st_m(timegeom) < '1514764800'::double precision) AND st_contains(timegeom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geometry))
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_t_geom  (cost=0.00..4.36 rows=10 width=0) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (timegeom ~~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geometry)
Planning Time: 1.393 ms
Execution Time: 0.181 ms
```

###### The same query after creating the new index:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on huge_spatial_table  (cost=17.90..46.92 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((st_m(timegeom) > '1356998400'::double precision) AND (st_m(timegeom) < '1514764800'::double precision))
  Filter: st_contains(timegeom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geometry)
  ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=17.90..17.90 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=0 loops=1)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_t_geom  (cost=0.00..4.36 rows=10 width=0) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (timegeom ~~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geometry)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_t_geom_m  (cost=0.00..13.29 rows=500 width=0) (never executed)
              Index Cond: ((st_m(timegeom) > '1356998400'::double precision) AND (st_m(timegeom) < '1514764800'::double precision))
Planning Time: 0.621 ms
Execution Time: 0.044 ms
```

Demo 1: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2a7facd31bc4da5238ff1142f8a7b967)

Demo 2: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=398f326a20b462e958815ea23d694ad7)

**Note**: PostgreSQL 9.6 will reach EOL in 5 months, so I strongly suggest you to upgrade your system (currently 13). You're missing tons of really kickass features.

Comment: Thanks for answering and testing the solution:) I will test this, indexing this huge table takes some time though.

Comment: And we will soon upgrade PostgreSQL/PostGIS to the lateste version in Azure, which is just PostgreSQL 11 and PostGIS 2.5.1 sadly.

Comment: @kau perhaps this test scenario better reproduce your environment? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2a7facd31bc4da5238ff1142f8a7b967 in the end it will depend on the distribution of the `m` dimension, but in the scenarios I run I got at least three times faster with the new index. Have you considered parsing this information and storing it in a separated column and using it as a partition?

Comment: @kau shame. A lot happened since PostgreSQL 11 and PostGIS 2.5.. but it is definitely better than your current environment ;) cheers

Comment: Creating an index on st_m(geometry) and vacuuming did not alter the query plan in my case, where the new st_m index was not used (Filter as before). I see this had an effect with your dummy data, so perhaps it is related to my old Postgres version. 

At this point I do not understand the point of embedding a measure in the geometry. In this case is seems simpler just to use a timestamp column in stead of using PointZM with time embedded. My hope was that the gist_geometry_ops_nd index could handle 4-D data, but that might not to be the case..

Comment: @kau it could be indeed related to your old versions :( storing dates in geometries (m) is pretty useful for line strings with trajectories, but even then creating an extra column with the time range is much faster and easier to query. I'm not familiar with your data, but in case it won't hurt anybody I would try to store it in a separated column and go from there.. this will make your life easier.

Comment: @kau perhaps this will give you some hints : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67531720/2275388